# Akka - Common service actor: Identify or Extension

Tags: scala, akka, actor, identify

Lets say I have some commonly used by other actors service-layer actor. For example, an registry service that stores and retrieves domain objects:

```scala
case class DomainObject(id: UUID)

class Registry extends akka.actor.Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case o: DomainObject => store(o) // save or update object

    case id: UUID => sender ! retrieve(id) // retrieve object and send it back
  }
}
```

I do not want to explicitly pass instance of such registry into all actors who may use it. Instead of it, I want them to be able to somehow 'locate' it.

For this I can think of two solutions:

1. `Identify` message: each registry user actor knows registry actor name from some configuration and able to sent identification message to it. After `AgentIdentity` message is received back we are good to go:

   ```scala
   val registryName = ... // some name
   val registryId = ... // some id
   var registry = _

   def preStart() {
     context.actorSelection(registryName) ! Identify(registryId)
   }

   def receive: Receive = {
     case ActorIdentity(`registryId`, ref) => registry = ref
   }
   ```

   I do not like this way because right after user actor initialisation there is a phase when we do not know if there is a registry in system et all and thus do not know will we ever be able to operate or not.
2. Akka Extensions: I can create an extension which would:

   a. create instance of Registry actor in given Actor System on initialization;

   b. return this actor to user who needs it via some method in Extension.

   ```scala
   object RegistryKey extends ExtensionKey[RegistryExtension]

   class RegistryExtesion(system: ExtendedActorSystem) extends RegistryKey {
     val registry = system.actorOf(Props[Registry], "registry")
   }
   ```

The question is: which method is better and are Akka Extesions can be used for this at all?

Comment: I think you mean `context.actorSelection(registryName) ! Identify(registryId)`.  `actorFor` is another solution though it is deprecated in 2.2.

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely correct. Memory leaks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the extension idea is a good one as long as your registry actor is always going to be in the same `ActorSystem`.

Alternatively, using `actorSelection` (adapted from [Remote Lookup](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html#remote-lookup-sample-scala)):

```
class RegistryClient extends Actor {
  val path = "/path/to/registry/actor"
  context.setReceiveTimeout(3.seconds)

  def sendIdentifyRequest(): Unit =
    context.actorSelection(path) ! Identify(path)

  def receive = {
    case ActorIdentity(`path`, Some(ref)) ⇒
      context.setReceiveTimeout(Duration.Undefined)
      context.become(active(ref))
    case ActorIdentity(`path`, None) ⇒
      throw new RuntimeException("Registry not found")
    case ReceiveTimeout ⇒ sendIdentifyRequest() 
  }

  def active(registry: ActorRef): Actor.Receive = {
    // use the registry
  }
}
```

This will work for remote or local actors.

Let's look at the extension solution. [Actors are created asynchronously](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Creating_Actors_with_Props).  Therefore your extension constructor won't fail when calling `actorOf` if the actor fails to initialize.

If you want to know for sure that the actor failed to initialize then one way to know is to `ask` the actor something that it will respond to and `Await` a response.  The `Await` will throw a `TimeoutException` if the actor fails to respond.

```
class RegistryExtension(system: ExtendedActorSystem) extends Extension {
  val registry = system.actorOf(Props[Registry], "registry")
  implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(500.millis)
  val f = registry ? "ping"    // Registry should case "ping" => "pong" 
  Await.result(f, 500.millis)  // Will throw a TimeoutException if registry fails 
                               // to respond
}
```

The `TimeoutException` will get thrown when you call `RegistryExtension(system).registry` the first time.

Comment: Yes, Registry always will be in the same system as actors using it.

My main concern is how Extension behave with fault tolerance? 

If by any means Extension will not be able to instantiate an registry actor, will it result in user actor exception during invocation of Extension .registry method?

Or it will result in error on Extension init?

Comment: I've decided to used mixed approach in system: `Identify` where low coupling or remoting is required and Extensions for actors who should be in the system for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

How about the [Cake Pattern](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/) or a Dependency Injection library such as [subcut](https://github.com/dickwall/subcut).

Derek Wyatt mentions DI in his book 'Akka Concurrency' instead of using too much actorFor to look up actors:
http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=289&thread=347118

Comment: Well, I would like to keep project dependencies at minimum for now. So, I guess, another lib just for DI of actors to another actors is out of bounds.

Comment: The Cake Pattern requires no extra dependencies. Just core Scala.

Comment: This is a classic case where Dependency Injection is the correct tool. You don't need to do anything heavyweight like import Spring and start using XML all over the place, just have the Registry actor ref be a constructor param for all Actors that depend on it, and chase through those changes until you find yourself creating one at application bootup and passing it around the whole app.